# Matrix rotation decreases the bias in estimation of linear regression coefficient?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear-model

Let's say we have a linear regression problem:
$$
y = x\beta + z\alpha + \epsilon
$$
for simplicity, we assume that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all $x\times 1$ vectors and both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scalars.

Now, let's say we try to estimate $\beta$ with the following two methods:

The first solution is:
$$
\hat{\beta_1} = (x^Tx)^{-1}x^Ty
$$
which is the standard solution of linear regression.

The second solution is:
$$
\hat{\beta_2} = (x^TRx)^{-1}x^TRy
$$
where $R=(zz^T+I)^{-1}$.

This second solution is equivalent to the linear regression solution of $x_r$ and $y_r$, where
$$
y_r = R^{\frac{1}{2}}y \\
x_r = R^{\frac{1}{2}}x
$$

Surprisingly, $\hat{\beta_2}$ has distinctly less bias than $\hat{\beta_1}$. I wonder why such a rotation can work so well. What is the idea behind rotating the matrix in such a manner?

Here are some Python simulation codes to have a look at this amazing power of matrix rotation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg as scialg

alpha = 10
beta = 10

x = np.random.normal(size=[5, 1])
z = np.random.normal(size=[5, 1])
y = z*alpha + x*beta + np.random.normal()
m = scialg.sqrtm(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(z, z.T) + np.eye(5)))
yt = np.dot(m, y)
xt = np.dot(m, x)

print np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(x.T, x)), x.T), y)
print np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(xt.T, xt)), xt.T), yt)
```

This question is an extension of a [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292398/in-linear-regression-is-there-any-relationship-for-beta-and-the-beta-of-its-rot) I asked. But that one might be too general and no one has answered it. I hope we can figure this out with more concrete examples this time.

Comment: Is this somehow related to interaction terms? After all you're just stirring together $x$ and $z$.

Comment: Also, is that really a valid rotation? AFAIK rotations have to be orthogonal, and that matrix $R = (zz^T + I)$ doesn't seem orthogonal.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Thanks. I thought a matrix multiplication can be called "rotation". If that's not the case, maybe we don't call it rotation, but the empirical result still holds.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Sorry I am sure I understand what you mean by interaction term?

Comment: I think your equations are all wrong, the $\beta_1$ solution is correct for the vector x =(x, z), not for individual variables x=x separately

Comment: @seanv507 I am not interested in estimating $\alpha$. For $\beta_1$, $x$ just stands for $x$ itself. This is more like that in a real world scenario, we will never actually know $z$, but maybe we can know $zz^T$

Comment: (1) Could you explain the basis for claiming "distinctly less bias"? (2) This appears just to be generalized least squares, with $R$ playing the role of the weights.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. 1) I don't have a well-defined measurement, but when I run it 10000 times with different random seeds, $\hat{\beta_2}$ always has the smaller bias. The averaged squared error between $\hat{\beta_2}$ and $\beta$ is 0.00021, while that number of $\hat{\beta_1}$ is 0.1929. 2) But why the role $R$ plays is helpful? (i.e. why we want to weigh $x$ and $y$ like this?)

Comment: Because this is just one specific case of the model, the "lack of bias" could be entirely an accident.  Since neither "solution" actually is one, trying to compare them would seem to be a fruitless exercise.

Comment: @HaohanWang consider the linear regression model you specified here, $y = XB = \left(\matrix{x & z}\right)\left(\matrix{ \beta \\ \alpha }\right)$. An "interaction term" between $x$ and $z$ would be $X = \left(\matrix{x & z & x^T z}\right)$, and a fully quadratic model would be $X = \left(\matrix{x & z & x^T z & x^T x & z^T z}\right)$, with $B$ expanded appropriately to match.